# How to chain joins in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of dataframe that I need to join:

My current method is a big ugly

```
testdf1
    .join(testdf2, Seq("uuid","datestr"), "outer")
    .join(testdf3, Seq("uuid","datestr"), "outer")
    .join(testdf4, Seq("uuid","datestr"), "outer")
    .join(testdf5, Seq("uuid","datestr"), "outer")
    .join(testdf6, Seq("uuid","datestr"), "outer")
    .join(testdf7, Seq("uuid","datestr"), "outer")
```

Given an seq of dataframes, is there a way to apply the same operations

```
Seq(testdf1,testdf2,testdf3,testdf4,testdf5,testdf6,testdf7)
```

How to write a generic function that joins them all?

Comment: in Scala, `foldLeft` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
val dataframes = Seq(testdf1,testdf2,testdf3,testdf4,testdf5,testdf6,testdf7)
```

you can use `reduceLeft`

```
val joinedDF = dataframes.reduceLeft((df1, df2) => 
    df1.join(df2, Seq("uuid", "datestr"), "outer")
)
```